# store XMLHttpRequest.responseText as variable :(

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, responsetext

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

```
try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
var result = ajaxRequest.responseText;      
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "vartest.php", true);
document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = result;
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is because Ajax is asynchronous, and `result` isn't set yet when you do this (plus the `var` makes it local to the function anyway, you'd have to remove that).

The best thing to do would be to move the `innerHTML` line into the readystatechange callback.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
   document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;;      
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to use the result as a variable elsewhere, and not just in the span tag I have. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Earl you'll need to set the variable in the onreadystatechange function, and it will be available there at a time you can't predict. You'll have to change your script to cater for that. There is a possibility to make calls synchronous (so that the script halts until the call was made) but that is highly discouraged practice because it can make the browser freeze

Comment: Fwew, I am so new to this I don't even know what that means Ha. Sorry to trouble you all. This script is not important to me, just looking for any good method to store the responseText as a variable.

Comment: I understand pretty well how to store a value as a variable and pass it to the php file to grab, just not the other way around unfortunately.

Comment: @Earl to store the response text in a variable, you just need to remove the `var` keyword, but you can't rely on it being available after you make the call. The Ajax call is made in the background and returns when it's done. That's why everything depending on the call's result needs to be in the onreadystatechange callback

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//this is in the global scope
//so it's available anywhere

**var result;**

function ajaxFunction(){

    var path = 'http://localhost/php/';
    var fileName = 'yourCode.php';


    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                       **result = ajaxRequest.responseText;**
        }
    }


    ajaxRequest.open("GET", path+fileName, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      result = ajaxRequest.responseText;        
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "vartest.php", true);
document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = result;
ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: as said, you can't rely on `result` to be available immediately after you make the call. You need to understand the asynchronous nature of Ajax and re-work your application accordingly

Comment: Ok. I will spend more time looking into this. Thank you for advise.