# save XMLHttpRequest.responseText in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this Question was asked 2 times before, and i couldn't get it to work anyways.
After i went through the posts [saving-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-in-a-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244031/saving-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-in-a-variable) and [store-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-as-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050387/store-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-as-variable?rq=1) i learned about Calling a Callback Function, because the XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous. (Seems obvious anyway)

So, i've created my phpfile checkemail.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ //if we get the email sucessfully
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

    if(!empty($email)){

        $email_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(`email`) FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email'");
        $email_result = mysqli_fetch_row($email_query);

        if($email_result[0]==0){
            //haven't found the email in the DB
            echo "0";
        } else{
            //found the email in the DB!
            echo "1";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So my outcome is either 0 or 1, wheter the email is already taken in the Database.

To my Javascript Code and my problem for this Thread:

```
function callback(responseText){
    var save = responseText;
    return save;
}

function checkemail(email){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "./inc/func/checkemail.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Send the data to PHP
    hr.send('email='+email);

    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            console.log(hr);
            console.log(hr.responseText);
            callback(hr.responseText);

        }
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, `console.log(hr.responseText);` in the inheritet function 'onreadystatechange' gives me the absolutely right result.

But, when i call the function `checkemail('test@test.com')` the function callback isn't called, or do i missunderstand something there?

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

---

I've also tried this, because it would be more logically to me (when the console.log in the same block of code gave me the right result already...) :

```
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            console.log(hr);
            console.log(hr.responseText);
            return hr.responseText;
        }
    }
```

---

In another post i've seen the statement

> If you change your function call to `hr.open("GET", url, false);`, that should make your call synchronous and JavaScript will wait until response is received.

Absolutely, as i said before i want call `if(checkemail('test@test.com')=="1")`... Will this adice help in any way? I couldn't get it to work so far... sadly :(

---

Now that @Hawk gave me some tips, i've tried some more ways to get my function to return true or false.

But I'm wondering if maybe my function can't call the function `callback`

```
function callback(responseText){
    var save = responseText;
    return save;
}
function checkemail(email){

    var email = email;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "./inc/func/check_email.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Send the data to PHP
    hr.send('email='+email);
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            email=hr.responseText;
            //return email
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="email is used already: "+email;
            return callback(email);
        }
    //return callback(email);
    }
}
```

Is there a difference between defining the function callback **outside** the function checkemail or do i have to define it **inside** the function checkemail like this:

```
function checkemail(email){
    function callback(responseText){
        var save = responseText;
        return save;
    }
    var email = email;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "./inc/func/check_email.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Send the data to PHP
    hr.send('email='+email);
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            email=hr.responseText;
            //return email
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="email is used already: "+email;
            return callback(email);
        }
    //return callback(email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function checkemail(email)
{
var email = email;
//code
if( hr.readystatechange == 4 & hr.status == 200 )
{
email = hr.responseText;
}
}
```

that way email will change and be stored in email inside function scope and stay there when function executes, hope it helps :)

try changing the part where you have called the callback(hr.responsetext) to this

return callback(hr.responseText);

that way you are returning a function that in turn returns save..i pray that works.. :)

please let me know if it works

Comment: But how do i return this variable of the function asynchronously?

Comment: what do you mean? the request is already being processed asynchronously, isn't it?

Comment: i want `checkemail('test@test.com')` to return the `hr.responseText`.

I get the point of where when i set the variable email, the data is saved.

But when i return it, it isn't returning the new and overrwitten data:

 `function checkemail(email){var email = email;
 if( hr.readystatechange == 4 & hr.status == 200 ){email = hr.responseText;}
 return email;}`

Comment: when you 'return email;', it is returning the email but to see it on the window, you have to use some sort of text output unless you're using it on the console. you could try using document.write to see the returned value or try calling your checkemail in the console because the returned value is not parsed as text code, it is simply being returned and not shown in the window.

Comment: eg. function add(x, y){return x + y}, when called will not show the result on the window but will show the result when you use document.write(add(5, 6)). i hope that makes sense

Comment: so, i have no way to bypass it?

Absolutely, i just want to check `if(checkemail('test@test.com')=="1")`

Comment: that should work since the function is processing the param given

Comment: it should work, yeah! but it isn't unfortunately... im working on making it work for two days now.

when i try `if(hr.readystatechange == 4 & hr.status == 200){email = hr.responseText;document.getElementById('status').innerHTML="email is used already: "+email;}`
it is working without any flaw, but as soon as i try to return the variable it isn't

Comment: so the code i sent is working?
are you returning from inside the scope of the if statement or outside the scope of the if statement though i don't think the scope is in blocks, in Javascript, scope is in functions..

Comment: the variable `email` is declared in the parent function `checkemail`, i'm re-writing the variable **inside the 'child' if statement** AND here is the point:
When i `return email;` **inside the if-statement** (where i thought, i have to return it) it isn't returning anything at all - running the function from both the console or via link - 
And when i `return email;` **outside the if-statement** it is returning the email passed to the function originally, cause the HttpRequest hasnt returned anything

Comment: got it, your httprequest won't return anything because it is not a function, the onreadystatechange is a property and not a function so if you want to return something, try encapsulating your xmlhttp in another function..because functions return and your function returns email. if you don't get it, let me know and i will try to code it up for you

Comment: i haven't got it to work. I've edited my Question, maybe you can give me some more tips.

Thanks, that you won't give up on this ;)